# How would you impose a parent instance to its child model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

so here's the thing:

```rb
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :wheels
end
class Wheel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
end
c = Car.first
p c.to_s
c.wheels.each do |w|
 p w.car.to_s
end
```

outputs:

```
"#<Car:0x00000001a4f2d0>"
"#<Car:0x00000001aee880>"
"#<Car:0x00000001ae2300>"
"#<Car:0x00000001ad5ab0>"
"#<Car:0x00000001aca0e8>"
```

I am absolutely sure I do NOT want to search in the DB and load new instance of the car for every its wheel. What strategy would you suggest? I have no idea where to start..

(the place where I intend to cal `wheel.car` is so deep that simply there's no way to hold car's instance)

**EDIT:**
(an answer to question of @BillyChan & @NitinJ)
This example is crudely simplified but I'll try to stick to it. Put away that I do not like the idea of loading again from db for every association in general (but I guess that's only on the programmer how he writes the code) I actually have a reason for this, let me try to explain it as follows:
Consider cancan ability.rb :

```
can :be_taken_off, Wheel do |w|
  !w.car.is_mooving?
end
```

so to make the answer to the closest point (thanks to @ChrisPeters & @NitinJ):

```
//in controller
@car = Car.first include: [wheels: :car]
@car.stop_moving
//in view
<% for wheel in @car.wheels %>
  <%= link_to 'take off', '..' if current_user.can? :be_taken_off, wheel %>
<% end %>
```

**BUT THEN AGAIN:**
(what suits me better) Since a) loading the `@car` instance is dug down inside cancan's `load_and_authorize_resource` and b) even if i would overwrite this method (actually simple task), it's not good to always load all wheels.. I guess I'll end with this:

```
<% if @car.has_wheels? %>
  <% for wheel in @car.wheels %>
    <% wheel.car = @car %>
    <%= link_to 'take off', '..' if current_user.can? :be_taken_off, wheel %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I'd love to find out a way for something like this: `@car.wheels.include(car: @car).each`

So if you don't have any better idea, i'll actually mark @NitinJ's answer as correct (although not suitable for my case). Thanks anyway!

Comment: Are you able to eagerly load via `includes`? `c = Car.includes(wheels: :car).first`. I only ask because I'm not sure what would happen myself.

Comment: So you've already know this car is actually that car. What's the point you want to call that car again when dealing with wheel?

Comment: What @ChrisPeters suggests sounds correct to me. [Includes is the preferred way to load](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-multiple-associations) those associations together when querying.

Comment: @BillyChan yes if he is already having the car instance than there is no logic to again access car through wheel

Comment: I would try my best to consider the answer to @BillyChan's question/point. But perhaps my suggestion is unavoidable based on your specific situation.

Comment: I've edited the question as answer

Answer (score 1):

try with this `Car.first(include: [wheels: :car])` this will run only one query . but i do not like the idea to reload the Car

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to do this,

```
@car = Car.first # The car instance

@car.wheels.each do |wheel|
 p wheel.name # different name, since there are different wheels for one car(@car)
 p @car.name # same name, since its the same car
end
```